# Are Google Play billing security recommendations only for piracy prevention?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play-services

The instructions for Google Play's billing service (in-app purchases) mention a number of things you should do to hide your app's public key and create a complicated "payload" string unique to each user and each of their purchases for security reasons.

My question may be ignorant, but I know absolutely nothing about hacking and what is possible.

When they say "secure", are they only referring to security from piracy of my app? Or do I need to worry about more malicious things, like them somehow being able to hijack my developer account with Google, or modifying my app so it could do harm to my users?

I don't want to add an Internet permission to my app just to do DRM for the one dollar in-app purchase I'm putting in it, and neither do I want to have to host a website and learn some server side programming just to keep my app working. I'm willing to do a small amount to obfuscate and limit piracy, but I'm not willing to put a lot of time into it, because I doubt it will increase my revenue enough to justify the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are referring to the Android In-App Billing "[Security and Design](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_best_practices.html)" best practices which are specific to Android in-app transaction security only.

A malicious hacker may find ways to access your in-app digital goods without actually paying for them. However, there are multiple and effective solutions to thwart hacking attempts.

I recommend to watch this [Google I/O presentation](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TnSNCXR9fbY) that addresses such issues.

Comment: So, the worst that can happen if I fail to make it secure enough is that people pirate my stuff? They aren't going to hijack my developer account or replace my apk on the store, by figuring out my private key? The reason for my question is that in computing I usually equate the word "security" with accounts getting hacked, not piracy.

Comment: Correct, they will just get the digital item for free.